# Fancybox doesnt open onclick submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

When I fill in my form and send it the fancybox is not coming up.
Here is the code i am using for the fancybox:

```
<div class="hidden" id="fancybox-popup-form">
        (your Fancybox content goes in here)
    </div>
<style>
.hidden { display: none; }
</style>
```

This is the confirmtation text i filled in at the plugin Gravity forms

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      $('#gform_submit_button_2').click(function () {
        $#gform_submit_button_2([
            { href : '#fancybox-popup-form' }
        ]);
    });
   </script>
```

And this is the HTML for the button where i need to click on the fire the function

```
<input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_2" class="button gform_button" value="Verzenden" tabindex="6" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_2&quot;]){return false;}  window[&quot;gf_submitting_2&quot;]=true; ">
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The inline clickhandler seems somewhat weird, JS parser doesn't know HTML. Instead of that, you could just prevent the default action in the jQuery click handler.

Answer (score 0):

> When I fill in my form and send it the fancybox is not coming up.

When you send it the page will be refreshed by the submit so your fancybox will not shown, so try to prevent the default action (submit) using `preventDefault()` :

```
$('#gform_submit_button_2').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Your code
})
```

Hope his helps.